# JUnit Mockito always returns false in assertEquals when comparing boolean values

Tags: java, junit, mockito, assert

JUnit Mockito always returns false in assertEquals when comparing boolean values.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class UserServiceTest { 
    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testIsAccountBlocked() {
        Boolean accountBlocked = userService.isAccountBlocked("username");
        assertEquals(true, accountBlocked);
    }   
}
```

This method always return false even if the username is blocked. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Apart from the problems with "false" that others already solved, you seem to be mocking everything - including the object you are testing (I guess you want to test userService). You should only mock collaborators of the tested object. If your goal is to test the logic of userService.isAccountBlocked() then you need to mock userRepository and instruct it to return some canned value and don't mock the userService.

Answer (score 4):

There's no JUnit [assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) with 2 booleans so you need to use different method - [assertTrue](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)):

> Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError without a message.

```
assertTrue(accountBlocked);
```

But in your case your class is mocked and therefore by default all its method with Boolean return value will return false

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

So unless you mock the method behavior using `when` you can assertFalse it

```
assertFalse(accountBlocked);
```

Comment: It is still throwing false

Comment: How can we mock the method behavior using when?

Comment: @kavya for example add `Mockito.when(userService.isAccountBlocked("username")).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: @kavya I think it is helpful to read [Mockito's manual](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't mocking any behavior. By default, calling a boolean method on a mock returns false.

To mock the behavior you are looking for:

```
Mockito.when(userService.isAccountBlocked("username")).thenReturn(true);
```